# Redirect a section of page

Tags: html, jsp

Is it possible to a particular `div` section redirect to some other page, and other element of the page should not be affected by that redirection.

Comment: Please add more details of your problem and provide a fiddle if possible

Comment: is there any JSP fiddle??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do this in multiple ways:

1. If your include is **static** (not changed at request time), you can use **include directive**:

```
<div>
        <%@ include file="header.html" %>
</div>
```

2.If you want to include that section **dynamically**, you may either use **`<jsp:include>`** action like this:

```
<div>
....
    <jsp:include page="header.jsp" />
....
</div>
```

Or **`<c:import>`** that is more flexible and also can be used for **external Urls** (include from another site)

```
<div>
     <c:import url=”http://www.example.com/foo/bar.
</div>
```

3. Another approach would be to use **'AJAX'**. in this case after the page is loaded, you use javascript to request to second url and put its content inside some HTML tag.
* note that in this approach, **search engines** will not see the content of that section.

4.The simplest way is to use IFrame to render the second section. But if you are using JSP, the recommended way is the first or second approach.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is either [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/AJAX) or an [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe).